# CPU and memory usage in percentage for all processes in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Is there a way for viewing CPU and memory utilization in percentage for all running processes in `PowerShell`?

I have tried the following:

```
Get-Process | %{"Process={0} CPU_Usage={1} Memory_Usage={2}" -f $_.ProcessName,[math]::Round($_.CPU),[math]::Round($_.PM/1MB)}
```

Along with it I have parsed this information and calculated memory usage percentage from total memory, but couldn't get the same for CPU since by this command it show CPU time division in processes not utilization per se.

Used the following commands for total memory and total cpu utilization:

1. TOTAL PHYSICAL MEMORY

   `Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | %{"{0}" -f $_.totalvisiblememorysize}`
2. TOTAL CPU UTILIZATION

   `Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Select-Object -expand LoadPercentage`

Any help would be appreciated. I need it in the following format:

```
PROCESS=process_name CPU=percent_cpu_utilization_by_process MEMORY=percent_memory_utilization_by_process
```

Comment: Please take a look at the given answer, if any have answered for question or help, upvote or accept them, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `WMI` object `Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process` to collect all this data.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process `
    | Where-Object { $_.name -inotmatch '_total|idle' } `
    | ForEach-Object { 
        "Process={0,-25} CPU_Usage={1,-12} Memory_Usage_(MB)={2,-16}" -f `
            $_.Name,$_.PercentProcessorTime,([math]::Round($_.WorkingSetPrivate/1Mb,2))
    }
```

If you need the memory in a percentage of total memory you can add the following at the start to get the total RAM in the system.

```
$RAM= Get-WMIObject Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure -Property capacity -Sum | %{$_.sum/1Mb}
```

Then change the `WorkingSetPrivate` calculation to the following

```
([math]::Round(($_.WorkingSetPrivate/1Mb)/$RAM*100,2))
```

**Note** the CPU stat in this `WMI` object is rounded to the nearest present and I have calculated the current used memory in Megabytes. For more information on this class see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394323(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, helped me out tons!

Comment: What is `-inotmatch` here?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Case insensitive, do not match.

Answer (score 2):

The good answer given was for 'each' process' stats. I was looking for 'all' processes stats collectively. The above posts helped me put together this script which I found useful. Probably similar available in other threads but where google leads, then wherever you go, there you are:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -Property * | % {([math]::Round(($_.FreePhysicalMemory)/$_.totalvisiblememorysize,2))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Get-Counter cmdlet?

The Get-Counter cmdlet allows you to get performance counter data for local/remote machines.

Have a look at the blog for more details:

http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/powershell-get-cpu-usage-for-a-process-using-get-counter/

Answer (score 0):

Try this in powershell:

```
Get-Counter '\Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use'
```