# powershell to return values like a task manager

Tags: powershell

I want to use the powershell to return values, likes task manager.
However, the item of network usage cannot return correctly.
How can I modify the code? Thanks a lot.

```
$RAM= Get-WMIObject Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure -Property capacity -Sum | %{$_.sum/1Mb}
$cores = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
while ($true) {
    $tmp = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | 
    select-object -property Name, @{Name = "CPU"; Expression = {($_.PercentProcessorTime/$cores)}}, @{Name = "PID"; Expression = {$_.IDProcess}}, @{"Name" = "Memory(MB)"; Expression = {[int]($_.WorkingSetPrivate/1mb)}}, @{"Name" = "Memory(%)"; Expression = {([math]::Round(($_.WorkingSetPrivate/1Mb)/$RAM*100,2))}}, @{Name="Disk(MB)"; Expression = {[Math]::Round(($_.IODataOperationsPersec / 1mb),2)}}, @{"Name"="Network"; Expression = {get-counter "\Process($_.Name)\IO Read Bytes/sec"}} |
    Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch "^(idle|_total|system)$"} |
    Sort-Object -Property CPU -Descending|
    Select-Object -First 5;
    cls
    $tmp | Format-Table -Autosize -Property Name, CPU, PID, "Memory(MB)", "Memory(%)", "Disk(MB)", "Network";
    Start-Sleep 3
}
```

This code is modified from articles as follows:
 
1. [CPU and memory usage in percentage for all processes in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244580/cpu-and-memory-usage-in-percentage-for-all-processes-in-powershell)
2. https://superuser.com/questions/1314534/windows-powershell-displaying-cpu-percentage-and-memory-usage#new-answer?newreg=a9290345d72946db9c7f8fd2af10de0a
3. [Powershell Script - list process with cpu, memory, disk usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51745651/powershell-script-list-process-with-cpu-memory-disk-usage)

---

I add a variable $process to show the owner of each process, but there are missing some parameters. I cannot find any documents about Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process from microsoft, is that normal? The modified code as follows:

```
$RAM= Get-WMIObject Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure -Property capacity -Sum | %{$_.sum/1Mb}
$cores = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
$Process = Get-Wmiobject Win32_process -computername "myComputerName" | select *,@{Name='Owner';Expression={($_.GetOwner()).User}}
while ($true) {
    $tmp = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | 
    select-object -property Name, @{Name = "CPU"; Expression = {($_.PercentProcessorTime/$cores)}}, @{Name = "PID"; Expression = {$_.IDProcess}}, @{"Name" = "Memory(MB)"; Expression = {[int]($_.WorkingSetPrivate/1mb)}}, @{"Name" = "Memory(%)"; Expression = {([math]::Round(($_.WorkingSetPrivate/1Mb)/$RAM*100,2))}}, @{Name="Disk(MB)"; Expression = {[Math]::Round(($_.IODataOperationsPersec / 1mb),2)}}, @{"Name"="Network"; Expression = { $_.IOReadBytesPersec }}, @{Name="Username"; Expression = {($($Process | ?{$_.ProcessId -eq $Item.IDProcess})).Owner} |
    Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch "^(idle|_total|system)$"} |
    Sort-Object -Property CPU -Descending|
    Select-Object -First 15;
    cls
    $tmp | Format-Table -Autosize -Property Name, CPU, PID, "Memory(MB)", "Memory(%)", "Disk(MB)", "Network", "Username";
    Start-Sleep 1
}
```

The modified part is referenced from https://powershell.org/forums/topic/getting-percentage-cpu-time-and-owner-for-processes/

Answer (score 1):

Guo-Jyun Zeng, welcome to SO.

First and foremost, the reason your 'Network' section isn't showing anything is because variable expansion is failing.  Let me explain--while PowerShell understands basic variables to expand inside of double-quoted strings, it does not directly understand slightly more complex objects that have their own properties.  So the problem you're having is here:

```
 @{"Name"="Network"; Expression = {get-counter "\Process($_.Name)\IO Read Bytes/sec"}}
```

Since '$_.Name' is inside the double-quotes, PowerShell doesn't know what to do with it.  There are a couple of ways you can easily accommodate this:

```
 @{"Name"="Network"; Expression = {get-counter "\Process($($_.Name))\IO Read Bytes/sec"}}
```

or using string tokens:

```
@{"Name"="Network"; Expression = {get-counter ("\Process({0})\IO Read Bytes/sec" -f $_.Name)}}
```

However, in my tests to reproduce, simply running Get-Counter returns a complex object.  That is, an object that has it's own properties and methods so this shouldn't work anyway.  In targeting the resulting property I thought you'd be after (Get-Counter "\Process(ProcessName)\IO Read Bytes/sec").CounterSamples.CookedValue, the script never returned data at all--like the Get-Counters were taking too long or something.

However, 'Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process' already appears to have an equivalent property for the counter you seem to want data for:  IOReadBytesPersec.

The only thing I'd note is that both that property and the Process-specific performance counter for 'IO Read Bytes/sec' count ALL I/O, not just network.  In fact, looking at the processor object, I couldn't find any counters that were specific to Network-only.

Your CPU shows nothing when I run it because you're trying to divide by 0 in a lot of cases.  Looking at PercentProcessorTime, it doesn't specify anything about an aggregate number of all processors.  I wouldn't assume the load is divided across the cores as your code does--I could be wrong tho.

Finally, as a point of performance, you can significantly lessen the hardware impact of your script by rearranging some of the things you're doing:

1. Explicitly request the desired properties from 'Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process' so it doesn't default to all properties.
2. Consolidate the Select-Object -First 5 with your first Select-Object so you're only working on those 5 in the rest of the loop.

Here is some slightly modified code to show some of the changes I described:

```
$RAM= Get-WMIObject Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure -Property capacity -Sum | %{$_.sum/1Mb}
$cores = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
while ($true) {
    $tmp = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | 
    select-object -First 5 -Property Name, @{Name = "CPU"; Expression = {($_.PercentProcessorTime)}}, @{Name = "PID"; Expression = {$_.IDProcess}}, @{"Name" = "Memory(MB)"; Expression = {[int]($_.WorkingSetPrivate/1mb)}}, @{"Name" = "Memory(%)"; Expression = {([math]::Round(($_.WorkingSetPrivate/1Mb)/$RAM*100,2))}}, @{Name="Disk(MB)"; Expression = {[Math]::Round(($_.IODataOperationsPersec / 1mb),2)}}, @{"Name"="Network"; Expression = { $_.IOReadBytesPersec }} |
    Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch "^(idle|_total|system)$"} |
    Sort-Object -Property CPU -Descending
    cls
    $tmp | Format-Table -Autosize -Property Name, CPU, PID, "Memory(MB)", "Memory(%)", "Disk(MB)", "Network";
    Start-Sleep 3
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. However, my CPU is always 0 when I use "select-object -First 5 -Property". The CPU usage is too high without dividing the number of cores when I compare with task manager. In addition, I will try to add the user information in my code. My mother tongue is not English, please forgive my bad English.

Comment: @guo-jyunzeng, your English is fine.  =)  Let me know if there's anything further I can assist with.

Comment: I want to add the owner information of each process. I tried some methods like @{Name="Username";Expression={win32_process $_.getowner().user}}, @{Name="Username";Expression={$_.getowner().user}}, @{Name="Username";Expression={$_.startinfo.username}}, @{Name="Username";Expression={$owners[$_.id.tostring()]}}, @{Name="Username"; Expression = {$_.ComputerName}}, etc. However, they are all failed. So, I need your help again. Thank a lot.

Comment: This would be a good place to start:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/get-process-owner-and-other-info-with-wmi-and-powershell/